# Wait for function to finish before starting again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

Good Morning,

I am trying to call the same function everytime the user presses a button. Here is what happens at the moment..

User clicks button -> Calls function -> function takes 1000ms+ to finish (due to animation with jQuery and AJAX calls)

What I want to happen is every time the user presses the button it adds the function to the queue, waits for the previous call to finish, and then starts..

Is this possible?

Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing..

Thanks Matthew

Comment: You want to queue the animations and the ajax correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Functions are objects they can store properties. You can have your function increment a 'queue' property on itself every time its called (button pressed) and then at the end of the function execution, check if the queue property of itself is > 0, and if so, decrement the queue property by one and call itself again using `setTimeout`.

Comment: The best way to do this is with a setTimeout call. Otherewise, this is a recipe for a stack overflow. ;-)

Comment: +1 @draeton Good point! When/if the function calls itself at the end, it should be done in a setTimeout, with a delay as small as zero.

Comment: @draeton: Indeed, that also has the benefit that the browser's rendering engine can do something (and avoids the evil box "script Y appears to be busy for some time. Kill it?")

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this in my own application. The best suggestion I have for you is (assuming you already have your AJAX calls inside of a JavaScript function) to pass a callback function parameter into your JavaScript function. Then, in the `success` section of your AJAX call, call your callback function.

**Example:**

```
// In HTML <script> tags.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#queue").click(function() {
        GetMembers(GetGroups(), MemberCallback));
    });
});

function GetMembers(userId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        //Initialized AJAX properties
        url: "/My/Project/Ajax/Page.extension",
        data: "{ 'groupId':'" + groupId + "'}",
        success: function (result) {
            callback(result.d);
        }
    });
}

function MemberCallback(members) {
    // Do your thing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback function to the one that makes the animation, once the animation finishes the callback it's called so you can do what you want.

Here follows an example from the jquery docs:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Put your code here, so it will be executed once the animation completes
  });
});
```

P.S.: Morning? It's almost midnight ;D

Comment: :D Almost midnight here, too. BTW, I suppose he doesn't know in advance (when that animation completes) whether the button is pressed again or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of a global queue/array where you add to the queue each time the user presses the button, then you'll want a callback in your function (such as in the `success` callback for jQuery) that does the work to check the queue and call the next function on the queue.

Comment: No need for global namespace polluting: just add a property to the object that works with it.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the button when they click it.  Enable it when the ajax routine is complete.