# PHP Ajax wait for function to finish before user can call it again Server-side

Tags: php, ajax

What i have is:

A user has 100 Points on his account. The function will subtract 10 points from his balance. Then the 10 points will go to another User.

The problem is that if the user spams the button 11 times, the other user still gets +10 points, even if the balance is at 0. This happens because the function is executed multiple times at once.

So I basically have the same problem like this question, but i have to handle it server-side.
[Wait for function to finish before starting again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514335/wait-for-function-to-finish-before-starting-again)

Example code:

```
function subtract() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'verify.php',
        data: {
            'token':token
        },
        complete: function(r) {
            var success = r.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

verify.php

```
$getCurrentBalance; //Points from Database
$subtract = $getCurrentBalance - 10;

updateBalance(); //Update the users balance with subtracted Points
```

So everything works great, but I have to check on the server side if the function has finished before the user can call it again.

Comment: can you post the content of `updateBalance();`?

Comment: @david `$database->getReference('users/'. $uid .'/points')->set($subtract);
` the function works, but i have to find a way to prevent a user from calling it multiple times

Comment: @IncredibleHat i thought of that, but that would be client-side or not?

Comment: why dont you disable the button upon clicking and then enable if again if the ajax completes? and you can also put validation in your sql before updating

Comment: @Miggy wouldn't that be client-side aswell? I mean, if the user wants to enable the button again via the console, he could?

Comment: The first one was on the client-side but the second is on the server-side which is validating the data before updating

Comment: @Miggy that sounds great but how do i write this in php?

Comment: just check if `$subtract >= 0` then `updateBalance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider it more like a comment but I strongly would like to point out that suggestion for client-side solution should not be a good way to solve problem because the client cannot and should not be trusted.

One way of solving it could be to "lock" the account while a transaction is ongoing. The lock could consist of a Boolean; true for unlocked and false for locked, as an example. The lock itself should be in the database table itself. From your programming you could 'deactivate' the button using css. That way you cover both cosmetic and functional.

Comment: @IncredibleHat are you serious? in made it very clear that i need it to be server-side.